# Could not convert the GeoJSON to ee.Geometry()

Tags: google-earth-engine, geojson, geopandas, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

My GeoJSON file's structure:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "10",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Id": "75"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                [ 71.000348,
                  31.199419 ],
                [ 71.00038,
                  31.198841 ],
                [ 71.000294,
                  31.198832 ],
                [ 71.000294,
                  31.197318 ],
                [ 71.0006,
                  31.197379 ],
                [ 71.000712,
                  31.197094 ],
                [ 71.000718,
                  31.196727 ],
                [ 71.001088,
                  31.19675 ],
                [ 71.001329,
                  31.196746 ],
                [ 71.001426,
                  31.196759 ],
                [ 71.001442,
                  31.197227 ],
                [ 71.001463,
                  31.197792 ],
                [ 71.001409,
                  31.198853 ],
                [ 71.001356,
                  31.199478 ],
                [ 71.000348,
                  31.199419 ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
```

```
import geopandas as gpd
import ee
import geemap
import os
import glob

# Authenticate Earth Engine (Note: if already not) or Authentication is expired, Remove "#" to run the next line.
# ee.Authenticate()

# Initialize Earth Engine
ee.Initialize()

# Specify the folder path containing GeoJSON files
folder_path = 'D:/file'

# Get a list of all GeoJSON files in the folder
geojson_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.geojson'))


# Iterate over each GeoJSON file
for geojson_file in geojson_files:
    # Load the GeoJSON file using geopandas
    try:
        nReserve = gpd.read_file(geojson_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading GeoJSON file {geojson_file}: {str(e)}")
        continue

    # Iterate over each feature in the GeoDataFrame
    for index, row in nReserve.iterrows():
        # Filter by feature_id
        feature_id = row['Id']
        nReserve_feature = gpd.GeoDataFrame([row])
        
        # Set the CRS for the feature
        nReserve_feature = nReserve_feature.set_crs("EPSG:4326", allow_override=True)  # Assuming EPSG:4326 for WGS84

        # Load the GeoJSON string into Earth Engine
        try:
            nReserve_geojson = geemap.gdf_to_ee(nReserve_feature)
            if nReserve_geojson is None:
                print(f"Could not convert the GeoJSON to ee.Geometry() for feature with ID: {feature_id}")
            else:
                print(f"Loaded feature with ID: {feature_id} from file {geojson_file} into Earth Engine")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error loading feature with ID: {feature_id} from file {geojson_file}. Error message: {str(e)}")
```

What I am trying to do.
I want to iterate multiple GeoJSON files with the same structure. First I want to iterate on all the GeoJSON files, after this,
I want to iterate over each feature in the GeoJSON file.
Then I filter using  Feature ID. Each feature has a unique ID.
Then I want to Load the GeoJSON string into Earth Engine.

Error.

```
Could not convert the geojson to ee.Geometry()
Error loading feature with ID: 75 from file D:/file\10.geojson. Error message: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Could not convert the geojson to ee.Geometry()
Error loading feature with ID: 77 from file D:/file\10.geojson. Error message: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Could not convert the geojson to ee.Geometry()
```

Comment: Pasting that JSON into geojsonlint.com gives several errors `Line 1: old-style crs member is not recommended, this object is equivalent to the default and should be removed
Line 1: a LinearRing of coordinates needs to have four or more positions
Line 1: position should not have more than 3 elements
Line 1: a LinearRing of coordinates needs to have four or more positions
Line 1: position should not have more than 3 elements`. Fix the data and try again.

Comment: Delete one leading and one trailing bracket from multipolygon coordinates in GeoJSON. `[[[[[.....]]]]]` -> `[[[[.....]]]]`.